# PhoneGap App vs PhoneGap + WebView + HTML5 Web App

Tags: iphone, android, cordova, ads

I have some app ideas that I want to release for free (with ads). I am a web developer that doesn't want to learn Java/Objective C at this point. I can build the ideas easily enough into  HTML 5 apps online.

Is there any reason I couldn't use PhoneGap to build the apps and put nothing in the apps but an ad, and a WebView pointing to my web apps online? I do not need camera or GPS support, and am just looking at PhoneGap as a way to get the apps on the different platforms easily. I like the idea of having the WebView point to the web apps since I can update them easier. (As opposed to building the HTML into PhoneGap)

Are there any technical reasons or developer guidelines that might get in my way? Any tips? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the Android market you really should not have any problems because there is no approval process. As for Apple, their guidelines can be strict, but they are more interface guidelines than anything. Read [this](http://mobileorchard.com/avoiding-iphone-app-rejection-from-apple/) as a guide if you're interested. Also, be warned that users generally dislike web apps, and occasionally leave 1 star ratings soley for that reason. Keep in mind that mobile internet is generally far slower than what you can get with a normal computer, so having the entire app pull things solely from the web will make the user feel that your app is slow. One of the main reasons for having native apps is that all the gui and much of the backend is built into the app, minimizing contact with the server.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will definitely be paying attention to the speed of the app, and if I can't get it to be quick enough to feel native (or close), I will perhaps try coding it native on Android to start.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I am trying to get figured out myself.

I think that the problem of trying to decide which is right (native vs. web) is a flawed process from the beginning. The right answer will always depend on what you need to do. From what you are explaining it sounds like building a native app would be overkill for what you are trying to do. A webview would be perfect.

Phonegap adds the additional benefit of allowing you to access some of the device api as well as offering you a presence in the app market for whichever device you are targeting.

Also...as a final note, keep in mind that mobile development is in it's infancy and there really are no tried and true best practices. But for a similar technology (Desktops)...look where some of their most successful applications are...Facebook? Twitter? YouTube?

Comment: A side note...Kevin has a good point. You need to make sure that your application flows smoothly, too much load time and you will have disappointed users. Some emerging frameworks help with this like jQuery Mobile or Sencha. And don't forget the speed you can get from a webservice serving up something like JSON.